# Get the Value of a Specific Cell in My GridView

Tags: jquery, asp.net

How can I get the value of a specific cell on my gridview via **jQuery** ?

My GridView

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdDetalheProposta" CssClass="StyleGrid" Width="100%" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataSourceID="dsGrid" BorderWidth="0" GridLines="None" OnRowDataBound="grdDetalheProposta_OnRowDataBound">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" CssClass="EstiloDalinhaAlternativaGrid"  HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
    <RowStyle CssClass="EstiloDalinhaGrid" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#e2dcd2" ForeColor="#000" CssClass="thGrid" Height="20" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Data" DataField="DataHora" ItemStyle-Width="1px" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Valor" DataField="ValorProposta" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Comentário" DataField="Comentario" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Inserido Por" DataField="NomeCompleto" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Credenciada Proponente" DataField="Apelido" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Status" DataField="Descricao" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ação">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%= acao %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I need that just the first row of my gridview, if the column 'Status' has a specific value, I put a specific value in the column 'Ação'. But just on my first row.

My rendered HTML - I need get the value 'Andamento' just in my first row

```
<div class="infoGridsemAba">
<div class='AgrupamentoPrincipal' style="background-color:#831611;padding:3px;">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;Detalhes da Proposta</div>
<div class='AgrupamentoSecundario' style="background-color:#ffc274;padding:3px;">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Abaixo listando detalhes da proposta</div>

    <div>
        <table class="StyleGrid" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="grdDetalheProposta" style="border-width:0px;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
            <tr class="thGrid" style="color:#000000;background-color:#E2DCD2;height:20px;">
                <th scope="col">Data</th><th scope="col">Valor</th><th scope="col">Coment&#225;rio</th><th scope="col">Inserido Por</th><th scope="col">Credenciada Proponente</th><th scope="col">Status</th><th scope="col">Ação</th>
            </tr><tr class="EstiloDalinhaGrid" align="center">
                <td style="width:1px;">04/01/2012 08:58:15</td><td>88888888,77</td><td>Teste</td><td>Fl&#225;vio Oliveira Santana</td><td>Central de Opera&#231;&#245;es</td><td>Andamento</td><td>

                </td>
            </tr><tr class="EstiloDalinhaAlternativaGrid" align="center" style="background-color:White;">
                <td style="width:1px;">04/01/2012 08:56:15</td><td>88888888,77</td><td>Teste</td><td>Fl&#225;vio Oliveira Santana</td><td>Central de Opera&#231;&#245;es</td><td>Andamento</td><td>

                </td>
            </tr><tr class="EstiloDalinhaGrid" align="center">
                <td style="width:1px;">04/01/2012 08:56:07</td><td>88888888,77</td><td>Teste</td><td>Fl&#225;vio Oliveira Santana</td><td>Central de Opera&#231;&#245;es</td><td>Andamento</td><td>

                </td>
            </tr><tr class="EstiloDalinhaAlternativaGrid" align="center" style="background-color:White;">
                <td style="width:1px;">04/01/2012 08:56:00</td><td>88888888,77</td><td>Teste</td><td>Fl&#225;vio Oliveira Santana</td><td>Central de Opera&#231;&#245;es</td><td>Andamento</td><td>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for size:

```
$("td:eq(5)", "#grdDetalheProposta tbody tr:eq(1)").html();
```

To set the next cell's value:

```
if ($("td:eq(5)", "#grdDetalheProposta tbody tr:eq(1)").html() === "XXX") {
            $("td:eq(6)", "#grdDetalheProposta tbody tr:eq(1)").html("ZZZ");
        }
```

Comment: Great!, it works to get the value of my first row in the column 'Status'. Now I Know the value, and I need to put a new value in my column 'Ação', in the same row. (Column 'Ação' is the next column). Do you know how can I do that ?

Comment: Updated answer to include answer to follow on question.

Comment: But the new value will be a <div>, this has some problem ?

Comment: Lucas - are you referring to my answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, hope fully this will work else you will need to tweak it little bit

```
//This statement should be on your aspx page where control resides
var myControlId = '<%=grdDetalheProposta.ClientID%>'; 
var column = $("#" + myControlId + " tr:first").next().children();
var text = $(column[5]).html(); // <= This is Zero base column index
```

To set the value

```
$(column[6]).html("new value"); // <= Ação is 6th column (1st column is zeroth)
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: I tryied but return null in alert. I try replace the 'li' in your var column, to 'td' but still null. Tryied 'nth-child(5)' and still null.

Comment: Great!, it works to get the value of my first row in the column 'Status'. Now I Know the value, and I need to put a new value in my column 'Ação', in the same row. (Column 'Ação' is the next column). Do you know how can I do that ?

Comment: But the new value will be a <div>, this has some problem ?